# PHP include - failed to open stream: No such file

Tags: php, include

I wrote a website in HTML but then I wanted the header and navbar portion in one file so I just had to change it once.  I changed all the pages to .php and added the php includes. However now I get an error on pages that I've put in folders so I could create cruftless links.

Header file: `/test/assets/header.php`

Works: `/test/index.php` contains `<?php include 'assets/header.php'; ?>`

Throws Error: `/test/company/index.php` contains `<?php include '/test/assets/header.php'; ?>`

Error:

```
Warning: include(/test/assets/header.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '/test/assets/header.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/local/php5/lib/pear')
```

I am having an issue linking to the header file that is in a folder in the root folder. I believe it is a simple issue of just not knowing how to input the URL.  If I attempt to include the full path to the header.php I get a `URL file-access is disabled` error

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you start a path with a `/` then it's an absolute path. Absolute mains to the actual filesystem root directory, not the virtual [`document root`](http://www.google.com/search?q=document%20root). This is why it fails.

Commonly this is what was meant:

```
include "$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/test/assets/header.php";
// Note: array key quotes only absent in double quotes context
```

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 5):

I was also facing the same warnings:

```
Warning: include(/test/assets/header.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '/test/assets/header.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/local/php5/lib/pear')
```

I solved them with the following solution:

You have to define your path then use include function as below:

```
define('DOC_ROOT_PATH', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/');
require DOC_ROOT_PATH . "../includes/pagedresults.php";
```

After that, you can use any directory structure.

Comment: `<b>Notice</b>:  Use of undefined constant DOC_ROOT_PATH - assumed 'DOC_ROOT_PATH'` **use `DOC_ROOT_PATH` instead `'DOC_ROOT_PATH'`**

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 0):

It's *not* a URL; it's a filepath (although you *can* use *full* URLs when the server configuration allows it).

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507